# Swiftで「curl -F」コマンドと同等の処理を実現したい

Tags: swift, swift3, curl

Swift 3.0にて下記curlコマンドと同等の処理を実現したいと考えておりますが、実装方法が不明のため、ご教授ください。

【実現したいコマンド】
    curl -X POST -F photo=@【画像ファイル（PNG）】 -F user_id=1 -F tag_id=1 http://X.X.X.X/

【具体例】
    curl -X POST -F photo=@/Users/test/test.PNG -F user_id=1 -F tag_id=1 http://192.168.1.1/test/

現状私が実装しているSwiftファイルは下記の通りです。

```
var request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:"http://192.168.1.1/test")!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"

// 画像データを読み出し、Data型に変換する.
let file: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData

//POSTするデータを設定する
let postString = "photo=\(file)&user_id=1&tag_id=1"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)


//タスクを作成する
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    print("response: \(response!)")

})
//タスクを開始する
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

別回答にもありますが、curlの-Fオプションではデータが`multipart/form-data`と言う形式で送信されますので、Swift側も同じことをやってやる必要があります。

- HTTPリクエストヘッダーに`Content-Type`として`multipart/form-data`を正しく指定する
- HTTPボディにはマルチパート形式でデータをパートごとに設定する

で、マルチパート形式の各パートは以下のようになります。(改行はCR+LF)

1. 境界線("--"に続けてContent-Typeで指定したboundary)+改行
2. パートヘッダー(複数行になることもある、当然各行で改行)
3. 空行(ヘッダー部とボディ部の境目を表す)
4. ボディ部のバイト列+改行

さらに全てのパートが終了した後、終了線を送信する必要があります。

1. 終了線("--"に続けてContent-Typeで指定したboundary、さらに"--")

以上説明した内容をコードにすると、こんな感じになります。

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.1/test")!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
// Content-Typeとして、multipart/form-dataを明示する、その中のboundary(境界線)の指定も必須
let boundary = UUID().uuidString
request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\"\(boundary)\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// 画像データを読み出し、Data型に変換する.
let file = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

//POSTするデータを設定する
var postData = Data()
//画像データ用のパートデータを追加する
postData.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートの境界線、先頭にも必要
postData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"test.PNG\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートヘッダーとしてContent-Dispositionと
postData.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //Content-Typeを指定する
postData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //空行がパートヘッダーとパートボディの境界線
postData.append(file) //パートボディとして画像をData化したものを追加する
postData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートボディの終了

//文字データ(user_id)用のパートを追加する
postData.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートの境界線
postData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //文字データの送信の場合(普通は)Content-Typeはなくてもサーバは受信してくれる
postData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //空行がパートヘッダーとパートボディの境界線
postData.append("1".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートボディとしてテキストをData化したものを追加する
postData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートボディの終了

//文字データ(tag_id)用のパートを追加する
postData.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートの境界線
postData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tag_id\"\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
postData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //空行がパートヘッダーとパートボディの境界線
postData.append("1".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートボディとしてテキストをData化したものを追加する
postData.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) //パートボディの終了

//全パートの終了を示す
postData.append("--\(boundary)--".data(using: .utf8)!) // end of all parts

request.httpBody = postData
```

(上記のように作った`request`の使い方はGETや単純なPOSTと同じ。)

---

少し大変に感じるでしょうか。私も普通のPOSTリクエストの送信くらいなら、「サードパーティのフレームワークなんて要らない」とか言い出す方ですが、`multipart/form-data`は、少し敷居が高いので、フレームワーク的なものを使った方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

multipart/form-data形式で作ります。
例えばこの辺り。
http://qiita.com/ryokosuge/items/8ccf6be8a7575649808a

自前で実装せずフレームワークを使えば少し簡単になります。
例えば、
Alamofire
(https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)
APIKit
(https://github.com/ishkawa/APIKit)
など、他にも多数あります。